# How to use filter with filterRaw instead raw beego

Tags: sql, go, controller, beego

How to use `FilterRaw` with `Filter` instead `Raw()`

This is my query

```
_, err := o.QueryTable("BillDetail").Filter("OriginalID", id).Filter("Date", xxx).Filter("Date", yyy).All(&bills)
```

I want to use filter like

```
rawSeter = o.Raw("SELECT bill_detail FROM WHERE original_i_d = ? AND WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?", id, xxx, yyy)
```

Because my `QueryTable` works wrong. It doesn't take `WHERE date =?` instead `BETWEEN`.

And I tried this

```
_, err = o.QueryTable("BillDetail").Filter("OriginalID", id).FilterRaw("WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?", xxx, yyy).All(&bills)
```

But it give me this error

> too many arguments in call to o.QueryTable("BillDetail").Filter("OriginalID", id).FilterRaw
>       have (string, time.Time, time.Time)
>       want (string, string)go

then how do I use properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_, err := o.Raw("SELECT *FROM bill_detail where original_i_d = ? AND date BETWEEN ? and ?", id, xxx, yyy).QueryRows(&bills)
```

You can add just query like this.